# ASP.NET Core AntiforgeryToken cookie is set to 1969 as expiration time

Tags: .net-core

I have setup an authentication using simply cookies. Somehow I saw in Application tab of Chrome that antiforgery token cookie expiration time is set to 1969, 31st December.

[image]

In `ConfigureServices` I have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(opts =>
{
    var ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    opts.Cookie.Expiration = ts;
    opts.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    opts.LoginPath = new PathString("/User/Authenticate");
    opts.ExpireTimeSpan = ts;
    opts.Cookie.MaxAge = ts;

    opts.Validate();
});
```

and in `Configure`

```
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Does it is a security concern ? Can that token be bypassed ? I didn't find any article related to antiforgery token default expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the date of a cookie to a time in the past (or minimum time) is a very common technique of telling the browser to delete a cookie. You should not be concerned.